# How do I delete all the rows of a table with a recursive structure (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, delete-row

I have a table in my DB, in which every row has a parent id which is the id of another row in the table (the table represents a tree-like structure). I would like to empty the table. But when I perform

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE true;
```

I get an error (foreign key constraint). How do I empty the table anyway?

Clarification: I want to delete the whole table's contents, not the tables themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, do you want to delete the whole table's contents? If yes, `TRUNCATE table_name;` will do it for you.

Comment: @andre: Yes, but I get the same error with TRUNCATE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to empty a self-referential MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615797/what-is-the-best-way-to-empty-a-self-referential-mysql-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your foreign key relationships, you need to specify `on delete cascade`.

EDIT: There's a pretty good reference right here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: +1! That is probably what the OP needs, although he did not ask for it directly.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
TRUNCATE table_name;
```

Comment: I get the same error. I think that my SQL statement is equivalent to yours.

Comment: @snakile: Interesting. I was pretty sure that this would work.

Comment: Same issue, but this worked perfectly for me.  I would 100% prefer an adjustment to the query versus an adjustment to the schema for On Delete Cascade.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the ON DELETE behavior, you can do this repeatedly until the table is empty:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT parent_id FROM table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete the rows that have no children.

So if the id foreign key is parent_id, do something like:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Then delete the rest:

```
DELETE FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

An old thread but I'll post my answer just to help anyone reading this question.

I had the same issue and I ended up setting the parent column to null before executing the delete statement.

```
UPDATE table_name SET parent_id=null WHERE true;

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE true;
```